# How do I call the start() & stop() methods in this to create functional audio controls?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I have a method `audioBufferSourceNode` which holds the audio file that has been loaded.

on line `136 which is line 13 below` the `start()` and `stop()` methods are being used on the audio node for other things, but I can't get it to ALSO do another thing. How do I  call these methods to play and pause the audio. I don't know the correct way to call `start()` & `stop()` methods so that I have buttons or divs that play/ pause the audio and also how do you use those methods to have a volume slider and mute button. How would I go about doing it?

Side Note: I was told declaring the variable 'audioBufferSourceNode' globally would be better practice, but not sure how to or what they meant exactly or if that even has anything to do with my problem.

so on `line 13` the `start()` and `stop()` methods are being used on the audio node.

```
 _visualize: function(audioContext, buffer) {
    var audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource(),
        analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(),
        that = this;
    //connect the source to the analyser
    audioBufferSourceNode.connect(analyser);
    //connect the analyser to the destination(the speaker), or we won't hear the sound
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
    //then assign the buffer to the buffer source node
    audioBufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;
    //play the source
    if (!audioBufferSourceNode.start) {
        audioBufferSourceNode.start = audioBufferSourceNode.noteOn //in old browsers use noteOn method
        audioBufferSourceNode.stop = audioBufferSourceNode.noteOff //in old browsers use noteOn method
    };
    //stop the previous sound if any
    if (this.animationId !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationId);
    }
    if (this.source !== null) {
        this.source.stop(0);
    }
    audioBufferSourceNode.start(0);
    this.status = 1;
    this.source = audioBufferSourceNode;
    audioBufferSourceNode.onended = function() {
        that._audioEnd(that);
    };
    this._updateInfo('Playing ' + this.fileName, false);
    this.info = 'Playing ' + this.fileName;
    document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 0.2;
    this._drawSpectrum(analyser);
 },
```

full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4hty6kak/1/

Web Audio API doesn't work on jsfiddle, so here's a live working demo:

http://wayou.github.io/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer/

Do you have any simple solid solutions?

Comment: Remove the "var" in front of the declaration and it will declare it as a global: `var audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.crea...` to `audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.crea...` Whether or not that is a "better" way is up for debate

Comment: alright, and then what do I do next?

Comment: If you're looking to start and stop it by button click (or keypress), my recommendation would be to break the start/stop processes out into separate functions, which can then be called by events... i.e. `$("#myPlayButton").click(function () { audioPlayer.play(); });`  I am assuming this is part of a larger object.

Comment: To play and stop, call `whateverIsThis.source.start()` & `whatheverIsThis.source.stop()`. For the volume, you'll need a [gainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode). Anyway, this question seems too broad and I can only advise you on reading about the [web audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Comment: @Nick yes im looking to start and stop it by button click on a php page, can you post your answer in how to do that with the code I've given, I'll mark that as the answer if it works.

Comment: @Nick I also post the full code on jsfiddle with the php/html, which is where the buttons should be, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Kaiido How is it broad? It's not broad at all, Im not asking about web audio API. Im asking how do I call the start() and stop() methods to make a clickable button that plays and pauses the song. I would like to know how do I do that? That is anything but broad. Im being very specific here.

Comment: No, you're using some code that makes use of the web audio API. You're wanting to extend this code, by adding  or make use of some functionality. Those are defined in the web audio API. What you want to do is not really difficult but for us to explain it to you, we will have to explain you from the beginning what is web audio API, and how it does work. SO is not the place for that so yes it is too broad.

Comment: Ps: my first comment did give you all you need to know for all your requests. Now just read the link I gave or [this one](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/?redirect_from_locale=fr#toc-context) (maybe a little bit outdated) and try to figure out how to make use of it. If in the process you need more specific help ("I did try x to do y, but it didn't worked as expected"), then you're welcome to ask a new question and I will be pleased to answer it if I come over it

Comment: Then I gave you those in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050264/how-do-i-call-the-start-stop-methods-in-this-to-create-functional-audio-co#comment-50127355)

Comment: @Kaiido that doesn't work..